# How to find out name package not installed apk?

Tags: android, apk, root

How to find out name package not installed apk?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c","aapt dump badging /sdcard/Downloads/ASD.apk grep package:\\ name ->"+"/sdcard/asd"}).waitFor();
```

Not Working.
aapt not found;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PackageManager`:

```
    PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFileName, 0);
    ApplicationInfo appinfo = info.applicationInfo;
    final String packageName = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appinfo).toString();
```

Comment: packageName='Taxi';, And I had to com.Taxi.asdadsd.

Comment: How to get the name of the package ?

Comment: Strange, that gives me package name... Try also this: getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo("apkFileName", 0).packageName